# How to get the business date N days ago in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write some code that will let me know the date n business days ago (excluding weekend). I have the following code that will find the date including weekends but can find a way to return a date that was n business days ago.

In the example below I return the date (including weekend) n days ago, but I need the date n business days ago.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

N = 2

date_N_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=N)

print datetime.now()
print date_N_days_ago
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34528583/2141635, you will need to adjust it slightly

Answer (score 0):

you need numpy busday offset function. The doc is pretty self explanatory.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.busday_offset.html

Answer (score -2):

You can use pandas as well.
Pandas is a good data analysis library.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days-experimental